# Nav links won't work unless at top of the page

Tags: html, css

I'm a full on beginner with this so forgive me if the answer is very obvious.
The links in my navbar section (class="nav-item") all work in the original position, but as soon as the page is scrolled they no longer work as links.

I've tried looking around for an answer and think it might be something to do with the actual links not moving with the actual nav-bar.

```css
.borderVisible {
  border-style: solid;

}

.headBanner {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.logoContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}

.navLinksContainer {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;

  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav-item {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mediumContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  padding-top: 110px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <nav id="nav-bar">
    <div class="borderVisible headBanner">

      <div class="borderVisible logoContainer">

      </div>

      <div class="borderVisible navLinksContainer">
        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section1">Section 1</a></div>
        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section2">Section 2</a></div>
        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section3">Section 3</a></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>
</header>


<div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section1">

</div>

<div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section2">

</div>

<div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section3">

</div>

<div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section4">

</div>

<div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section5">

</div>
```

Comment: you'r header tag must be inside the body tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header tag must be inside the body, then work with z-index for header.
In your code your link doesn't work because your mediumConainer div goes hover the header

```css
.borderVisible {
  border-style: solid;

}

.headBanner {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}

.logoContainer {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
}

.navLinksContainer {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;

  display: grid;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav-item {
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mediumContainer {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  padding-top: 110px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:2;
}

#header-img {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
}

#nav-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 95%;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Product Landing Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
    </head>

   

    <body>
    
     <header id="header">
        <nav id="nav-bar">
            <div class="borderVisible headBanner">

                    <div class="borderVisible logoContainer">

                    </div>

                    <div class="borderVisible navLinksContainer">
                        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section1">Section 1</a></div>
                        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section2">Section 2</a></div>
                        <div class="borderVisible"><a class="nav-item" href="#section3">Section 3</a></div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
        <div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section1">

        </div>

        <div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section2">
            
        </div>

        <div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section3">
            
        </div>

        <div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section4">
            
        </div>

        <div class="borderVisible mediumContainer" id="section5">
            
        </div>

    </body>
</html>




<!-- test script -->
<script src='https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set a background colour on your `mediumContainer` elements, you can clearly see that they **cover up** the links.

You need to put the `header` (which is the positioned element in the same containing block as the `mediumContainer` elements above them with `z-index`.

```
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice example of z-index messing with your setup.
As soon as you start to scroll, your `mediumContainer` elements slide in front of your navigation.

If you use a z-index on your header with a value of, say, 100 and add a z-index of less then 100 to `mediumContainer`, you should be good

Here's a fix: https://jsfiddle.net/w0e2jspL/